# readLine() throws Exceptions in chat program and i can't figure out why

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I wrote a small chat program, that cosists of 3 classes: TalkServer (the Server), TalkDienst (a thread-class that manages data exchange between clients) and ChatProgram (the client).

TalkDienst:

```
    public class TalkDienst extends Thread {
    private Socket send, rec;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private boolean sendClosed, recClosed;

    public TalkDienst(Socket send, Socket rec) {
        this.send = send;
        this.rec = rec;

        try {
            this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.rec.getInputStream()));
            this.out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.send.getOutputStream()), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // this.out.println("--- Partner found ---");
        System.out.println("Partner found");
        while (true) {
            try {
                String input = this.in.readLine();
                System.out.println("test");
                if (!input.equals(null)) {
                    this.out.println(input);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                closeall();
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                closeall();
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void closeall() {
        try {
            this.send.close();
            this.rec.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ChatProgram:

```
    public class ChatProgramm extends JFrame implements Runnable
{
    private Thread t;
    private Socket s;
    private Container c;
    private JTextArea ta;
    private JScrollPane sp;
    private JScrollBar sb;
    private JTextField tf;

    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    private boolean socketClosed;

    public ChatProgramm(Socket h)
    {
        this.t = new Thread(this);

        this.s = h;
        try 
        {
            this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.s.getInputStream()));
            this.out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.s.getOutputStream()), true);
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.t.start();
//Just some UI things...[...]

        this.ta = new JTextArea();
        this.ta.setEditable(false);
        this.ta.setText("--- Waiting for partner ---");

        this.tf = new JTextField();
        this.tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                if(tf.getText().length() > 0)
                {
                    out.println(">>>: " + tf.getText());
                    ta.setText(ta.getText() + "\n<<<: " + tf.getText());
                    tf.setText("");
                }
            }

        });

        this.c.add(this.sp);
        this.c.add(this.tf);

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                String input = this.in.readLine();
                System.out.println("warten");
                if(!input.equals(null))
                {
                    this.ta.setText(this.ta.getText() + "\n" + input);
                    this.sb.validate();
                    this.sb.setValue(this.sb.getMaximum());
                }
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                closeall();
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            } catch (NullPointerException e)
            {
                closeall();
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void closeall()
    {
        try
        {
            this.s.close();
            this.ta.setText(this.ta.getText() + "\n--- Connection lost ---");
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When i delete the comment on

> // this.out.println("--- Partner found ---");

in TalkDienst, then the program won´t work and will give me these error messages:  Left window shows TalkDienst, top right is client 1 and bottom right client 2

[Error messages and clients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTywX.png)

Here are the requested error messages in text-form:
TalkServer:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
        at TalkDienst.run(TalkDienst.java:40)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at TalkDienst.run(TalkDienst.java:42)
```

ChatProgramm 1: (started first)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ChatProgramm.run(ChatProgramm.java:131)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

ChatProgramm 2:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ChatProgramm.closeall(ChatProgramm.java:156)
        at ChatProgramm.run(ChatProgramm.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please copy and paste the text from the command prompt windows instead of linking to images.

Comment: Alright, i copied the exceptions!

Answer (score 0):

`println()` does not throw exceptions, including this one, which is thrown by `readLine()`, because you closed the socket and continued to use it.

Your end of stream checking is also wrong. The customary checking is:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null
    // ...
```

Comment: i dont get how i closed the socket and continued to use it! Could you please explain